# Query returns no results when data does not exist in both tables

Tags: mysql

So, I’ve got two tables.  Users contains basic user information and user_address contains user address’.  Pretty straight forward.

I have a search form that allows for users to be looked up.  One search field searches multiple columns using LIKE.
It allows for users to be pulled by their...

company name (listed under users table)
Name (listed under user address table)
Email address (user address table)
Phone 1 (user address table)
Phone 2 (user address table)

The form triggers an Ajax which passes the search value to the search page via $_POST.

$value is then assigned from the $_POST and is filtered and then passed to the mysql query.

On a normal case scenario where both the user exists and addresses exist for the user, the query below works perfectly.

**The problem is, that sometimes when a “user” is added to the database, an address isn’t entered right away. During this instance, when trying to search for a user, the user isn’t found.**

I need it to find the users whether an address is entered or not.  I have tried JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN, etc.  Nothing seems to be working.  And for some reason, left join SLOWS down the query and when the query is triggered, the page gets bogged down.

```
"SELECT u.id,u.company,a.name as address_name
FROM Users as u 
JOIN User_Address as a ON a.user_id = u.id 
WHERE a.name LIKE '%$value%' OR u.company LIKE '%$value%' OR a.email LIKE '%$value%' OR a.phone_1 LIKE '%$value%' OR a.phone_2 LIKE '%$value%' GROUP BY u.id”
```

Again the problem with the search is when a user exists in the User table, but no address exists for that user in the User Address table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is a bit tricky, because if I understand correctly, you want to have both the user and the address, even if the match is just in the user. That's why I would pull the matching into a subquery. This will also massively help with performance.

```
SELECT Users.id, Users.company, User_Address.name AS address_name
FROM (
  SELECT id AS user_id FROM Users WHERE u.company LIKE '%$value%'
  UNION
  SELECT user_id
  FROM User_Address
  WHERE a.name LIKE '%$value%'
  OR a.email LIKE '%$value%'
  OR a.phone_1 LIKE '%$value%'
  OR a.phone_2 LIKE '%$value%'
) AS matches
JOIN Users ON Users.user_id = matches.user_id
LEFT JOIN User_Address ON User_Address.user_id = Users.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

By the way, the `LIKE '%$value%'` looks like you're using string interpolation to build your query. This can be unsafe. Make sure your values are properly escaped and you understand the dangers and alternatives (like using a parameter binding library).

Comment: They are escaped and its for internal use only.  I’ll try this soon.  Thanks!

Comment: That did not do it.  It still searches the same exact way.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the "LEFT"  when copypasting. Edited.

Comment: That works perfectly.  Can you explain why you set it up like this?  I'd like to understand the difference.

Comment: I made two changes to your original query: 1) Moving the matching into the subquery. You'll see the reason if you think about it: If you match a user by `u.company` but you still want to query the `address_name` you somehow need to do the matching first and then read the address as well - this is what the subquery does. Also I chose to use UNION instead of LEFT JOIN inside the subquery. This is just because the actual joining would be unnecessary overhead in this case - we just want the matching `user_id`s.